# memory leak on game loop

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, raphael, game-loop

I am creating a game in javascript and my gameloop is called every 30ms, it leaks a lot of memory as task manager shows the firefox memory usage to increase by 400mb in about 20 seconds.
I am not familiar with how to make sure memory is collected in javascript.

```
function GameLoop(tick) {
  move(player1.ship);
}

function Player(name) {
  this.id = 0;
  this.name = name;
  this.ship = Ship(this);
}

function Ship(player) {
  this.pos = [1024/2, 768/2];
  this.vel = [0, 0];
  this.angle = 0;
  this.acc = 0;
  this.thrust = 0;
  this.west = 0;
  this.east = 0;
  this.turnRate = 5;
  this.player = player;
  this.size = [40, 40];
  this.ship = canvas.rect(this.pos[0], this.pos[1], this.size[0], this.size[1]);
  this.ship.attr("fill", "red");

  return this;
}

function move(ship) {
  var angle = ship.angle;
  var max_speed = 20;
  var acc_speed = 300;

  var acc = 0;
  if (ship.thrust) {
    acc = 0.25 * acc_speed;
  }
  else { //slow down
    if ((acc - (0.25 * acc_speed)) > 0) {
      acc -= 0.25 * acc_speed;
    }

    else {
      acc = 0;
    }
  }

  var speedx = ship.vel[0] + acc * Math.sin(angle);
  var speedy = ship.vel[1] - acc * Math.cos(angle);
  var speed = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(speedx,2) + Math.pow(speedy,2));

  var speedx = ship.vel[0] + acc;
  var speedy = ship.vel[1] - acc;
  var speed = speedx + speedy;

  if (speed > max_speed) {
    speedx = speedx / speed * max_speed;
    speedy = speedy / speed * max_speed;
  }
  ship.vel = [speedx, speedy];
  ship.pos = [ship.pos[0] + speedx * 0.25, ship.pos[1] + speedy * 0.25];
  ship.ship.attr({x: ship.pos[0], y: ship.pos[1]});
  ship.ship.rotate(angle);
  ship.angle = 0;

  delete this.thrust;
  delete this.west;
  delete this.east;
  delete old_angle;
  delete angle;
  delete max_speed;
  delete acc_speed;
  delete acc;
  delete speedx;
  delete speedy;
  delete speed;

  return this;
}

var player1 = new Player("Player 1");
setInterval(GameLoop, 30);
```

Ok I commented out some code and have found the offending line, its

> ship.ship.rotate(angle);
>   After commenting that line out javascript is using 4500K.
>   any idea why this is causing the problem, and how can I still rotate my object without this bit of code?

Comment: What is the definition of `Player`?

Comment: there's nothing in that that will leak, certainly nothing that would leak almost 1MB/loop.  How about you show the code that actually _does_ something?  e.g. the move animation?  As it is now, you're just changing `ship.angle`, `thrust` and `vel` and not doing anything with them.

Comment: Which version of Firefox? Before 7.0 FF would do a GC only if it hits a fixed upper limit of RAM ...

Comment: firefox 9.0.1, also just added the Player and Ship functions

Comment: @code_by_night -- still need code that draws the ship in its new position :)

Comment: @cwolves sorry, just added it in :)

Comment: why you `return this` in function `move` ?

Comment: I decided to put a return statement in there to see if it would make a difference, and so I just decided to return 'this'. I imagine it should probably be removed.

Comment: Is this `this.ship = Ship(this);` actually like that? Or does it use `new Ship(this)`?

Comment: var canvas = Raphael(0, 0, width, height);
and yes this.ship = Ship(this); is correct.

Comment: In that case `this` inside the Ship function refers to `window`, which seems unintentional (?). It could possibly be creating a circular ref on the line where it sets the attrs before rotating, but it seems a bit unlikely for it to cause such huge mem consumption. What does it actually do if you just leave it running? Will it crash with out of memory or something?

Comment: If I leave it running it usually goes to about 2.5gb of ram then crashes. I would need to leave it for 20mins or so to get that result.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Unless the rotate function causes some weird side-effects besides of the obvious, I can't really think of any reason why it would leak memory. In the past I've had some similar cases where it looked like some code was causing the leak, but in reality it was completely different, so it could be the real cause is not even that call.

Comment: What version are you using? 2.0 used to have a memory leak, fixed in 2.0.1. An alternative to .rotate(angle) is .transform('r' + angle).

Comment: I am running 2.0.1 I will try the alternative now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of [rotate](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.rotate) in RaphaelJS says the following:

> Adds rotation by given angle around given point to the list of transformations of the element.

That certainly sounds like a potential culprit.  The critical words there are *add* and *list*.

What does the [transform](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform) function show you when you rotate an element twice?  My suspicion is that calls to rotate accumulate larger and larger transformation strings.  if that's what's happening, you can reset the transform,

```
el.transform("");
```

and that should clear the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything is under control again.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything in your code snippet which would leak memory.

As pointed out by Eugen Rieck, Firefox (and others) sometimes don't do GC and/or free memory they have allocated until they actually have a reason to do it.

Have you tried using an actual memory profiling tool to see if your code is actually leaky? I'm not sure if Firefox has one, but there's one at least in Chrome.

Comment: I have opened it up in Chrome and the Chrome task manager uses about 2000K a second.

Comment: Try taking some heap snapshots with the Chrome dev tools' Profiler and post the results. I'm still not really sure that the code you've posted in your question is the culprit however.

Comment: not exactly sure what I'm posting, but under 'Object' its got over 900 other objects named 'Object @34866X' or something similar, each taking up around 2KB or so.

Comment: Try doing a heap snapshot once it's running, then wait a while and do another heap snapshot. Look at the difference between the object counts between each snapshot. If it looks like you're getting a ton more objects, it could be you have a circular reference somewhere, or possibly an array you're forgetting to clear. It could also be just that the GC isn't firing. You should be able to see if the GC is firing by using the timelines and CPU profiling, as it should show up there if I remember correctly.

Comment: check my question up top as I found the problem, still stuck on a solution however...